# Loading x rows from database at a time, showing them, loading next x rows and so on

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pagination

I have a database with multiple tables, each having millions of rows of data. In my Java appliaction, my task is to display certain data from certain tables depending on the arguments which I get from the user. I have successfully been able to load all of this data at once, but when there are 10 million rows, it takes a long time. I have found out about `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and `statement.setFetchSize(x)`, but these don't seem to work.

```
public static int getTableResults(Result_Controller okno){
    int i = 0;
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        String query = "SELECT h.\"Nazov hotela\", k.\"Nazov krajiny\", m.\"Nazov mesta\", h.\"Adresa hotela\", h.\"Hviezdicky\", p.\"Cena pobytu\", i.\"Typ izby\", h.\"Pocet izieb\" " +
                "FROM hotel h " +
                "inner JOIN izba i ON i.\"ID hotela\" = h.\"ID hotela\" " +
                "inner JOIN krajina k ON k.\"ID krajiny\" = h.\"ID krajiny\" " +
                "inner JOIN mesto m ON m.\"ID mesta\" = h.\"ID mesta\" " +
                "inner JOIN pobyt p ON p.\"ID hotela\" = h.\"ID hotela\" " +
                "WHERE h.\"Nazov hotela\" = ? " +
                "AND k.\"Nazov krajiny\" = ? " +
                "AND h.\"Hviezdicky\" = ? " +
                "AND i.\"Pocet posteli\" >= ? " +
                "AND p.\"Cena pobytu\" <= ? " +
                "ORDER BY h.\"Nazov hotela\"";

        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        pst.setFetchSize(150);

        pst.setString(1, okno.getText_nazov().getText());
        pst.setString(2, (String) okno.getKrajina().getValue());

        int pocet_hviezdiciek = Integer.parseInt((String) okno.getHviezdicky().getValue());
        pst.setInt(3, pocet_hviezdiciek);

        int pocet_osob = Integer.parseInt((String) okno.getOsoby().getValue());
        pst.setInt(4, pocet_osob);

        double cena_pobytu = Double.parseDouble(okno.getText_cena().getText());
        pst.setDouble(5, cena_pobytu);

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(pst);

        while (rs.next()) {
            okno.getOblist().add(new Vysledok_hladania(rs.getString("Nazov hotela"),
                    rs.getString("Nazov krajiny"),
                    rs.getString("Nazov mesta"),
                    rs.getString("Adresa hotela"),
                    rs.getInt("Hviezdicky"),
                    rs.getDouble("Cena pobytu"),
                    rs.getString("Typ izby"),
                    rs.getInt("Pocet izieb")));

            System.out.println(i++);
        }
        okno.getTable().setItems(okno.getOblist());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Result_Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
return i;
}
```

All in all I want to get these results and display them in batches, not all at the same time.

Comment: This looks like it should work just fine. Can you describe your problem in detail?

Comment: The process consists of the user inputing data, name of the hotel (Nazov hotela), country the hotel is in (Nazov krajiny), Number of stars the hotel has (Hviezdicky), Number of people to accomodate (Pocet posteli) and the cost of the stay (Cena pobytu). After this info is entered, the program connects to the database using the code above, gets the input using pst.setString etc and then returns a result set. Now the while cycle prints out the numebr of records that match the input, and should print it out right, but it goes on into millions until printing it out.

Comment: I have failed to metion this is displayed to a tableview in javafx gui.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the execution plan, but the problem must be the `ORDER BY`. PostgreSQL needs the complete result before it can begin to sort.

You may be able to get a “fast start-up” plan with a nested loop if you create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON hotel ("Nazov hotela");
```

In addition, you need to have an index for the join conditions (the ID columns) on all other tables:

```
CREATE INDEX ON izba ("ID hotela");
CREATE INDEX ON krajina ("ID krajiny");
CREATE INDEX ON mesto ("ID mesta");
CREATE INDEX ON pobyt ("ID hotela");
```

Comment: I have removed the `ORDER BY` statement and i have these tables joined by IDs. The problem is that the program waits until it has loaded the last result, and then displays them all at once.

Comment: Are there indexes on all the join conditions? Can you use `auto_explain` to capture the execution plan? That would help.

Comment: I dont know how to use `auto_explain`, and what do you mean by indexes on all the join conditions?

Comment: I have added the other index definitions. About [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html), follow the link. You need to add it to `shared_preload_libraries` and then set `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0` and `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` before running the query. Ideally set `auto_explain.log_buffers = on` and `auto_explain.log_analyze = on` for the test. Then you'll get the execution plan in the log file.

Comment: Ah sorry, i wrote to my teacher and it seems we will learn indexes later on in the semester. I dont know what the specific problem with this is, but i have found a workaround using the limit and offset in postgresql. I made a tableview with pagination, and for each page there are 15 records that i load when i click on the next page.